# I am facing an Attribute Error while using random() function in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use random library in Python. The code is as follows:

```
import random
#print random integer
rand_int = random.randint(1,10)
print(rand_int)
```

However VSCode is showing the error:

```
devjyotisinha@Devjyotis-MacBook-Air Udemy % python3 -u "/Users/devjyotisinha/Desktop/Python/Udemy/random.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/devjyotisinha/Desktop/Python/Udemy/random.py", line 1, in <module>
    import random
  File "/Users/devjyotisinha/Desktop/Python/Udemy/random.py", line 3, in <module>
    rand_int = random.randint(1,10)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'random' has no attribute 'randint' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

The code is working fine on online editors such as replit.com but VSCode is showing an error. What does the attribute error mean as I learnt that `randint` is an attribute of `random`?

Comment: Change your script filename to myrandom.py or something that isn't the name of a built-in or otherwise installed module and see what happens

Comment: If you feel if one's answer helps, you can upvote and accept by clicking the checkmark beside the answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you have a local file named `random.py`. Run the following code if you want to check in the future:

```
import random

print(random.__file__)
```

Follow the following:

```
# ⛔️ result if shadowed by local file
# /home/borislav/Desktop/bobbyhadz_python/random.py

# ✅ result if pulling in correct module
# /usr/lib/python3.10/random.py
```

Your file directory has `random.py` in it, DO NOT do this. Rename it! When you have a file with this, the VScode will immediately go to the file and try finding the `randint` method in it, which of course you don't have in your file.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try changing your file name, I can see it's random.py This might be the issue.